# Android Studio: Emulator shows no UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start the emulator through android studio, the emulator opens, there is a short flash and then it is just black no UI.

The created device is a **Pixel XL API 24**, the *graphics* is **Software - GLES 2.0** and I am using linux based OS.

I get the following error by starting the emulator

**WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null**

*EDIT - 2nd July'17:*

During the execution of the emulator, after a bunch of

**WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null**

messages, I get a **WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - IO Error while obtaining allocation status**

and then again a bunch of

**WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Emulator not ready yet, dev.bootcomplete = null**

messages and so on. At the end I get the following message

**WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.**

Comment: Have you tried to reconfigure the setting? Or create a new one?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops Yes, I deleted all devices and created a new one. So far, it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem and I follow `@ewaller` answer (in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224909))

to change the emulator configuration from **Automatic** to **Software...** will make the emulator work normally

[image]